# Alternatives to repeated use of partial when using clojure's `comp`

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Given a collection"

```
[{:key "key_1" :value "value_1"}, {:key "key_2" :value "value_2"}]
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
{"key_1" "value_1" "key_2" "value_2"}
```

An function to do this would be:

```
(defn long->wide [xs]
    (apply hash-map (flatten (map vals xs))))
```

I might simplify this using the threading macro:

```
(defn long->wide [xs]
  (->> xs
       (map vals)
       (flatten)
       (apply hash-map)))
```

This still requires explicit definition of the function argument which I am not doing anything with other than passing to the first function. I might then rewrite this using `comp` to remove this:

```
(def long->wide
  (comp (partial apply hash-map) flatten (partial map vals)))
```

This however requires repeated use of `partial` which to me is a lot of noise in the function.

Is there a some function in clojure that combines `comp` and `->>` so I can create a higher order function without repeated use of partial, and also which out having to create a new function?

Comment: if you want to go point-free, this would be an alternative: `(partial into {} (map (juxt :key :value)))`

Comment: also `(vals {:value "v1" :key "k1"})` (vs `(= {:value "v1" :key "k1"} {:key "k1" :value "v1"})`) is dangerous, since regular maps are not ordered (small ones are "by accident")

Comment: @cfrick's function is preferable. If you present the data as `[{:value "value_1" :key "key_1"} {:value "value_2", :key "key_2"}]`, your `(long->wide data)` yields `{"value_1" "key_1", "value_2" "key_2"}`. Beware of `flatten`!

Comment: @cfrick Thank you. I had not thought to use `juxt`. I am getting the data from a DB so I think to use this I would have to keywordize-keys first since the keys are strings.

Comment: @cfrick Ah I realise I wrote the question using keywords so my question was misleading in that respect.

Comment: IMO is your very first implementation the clearest one. One look and every clojure programmer will understand. Why the need to complicate things? If you removed the `defn` you're losing the naming of your arguments.

Comment: I think the lesson learned from all answers so far is that the threading macro solution is the clearest. It doesn't matter that defn is used. If anything, that further helps readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since many of the answers here already don't answer the original question, but
suggest different approaches, I put that one back up too.

I'd go with reduce and destructuring:

```
(reduce 
  (fn [m {:keys [key value]}] 
    (assoc m key value)) 
  {} 
  [{:key "key_1" :value "value_1"}, {:key "key_2" :value "value_2"}])
```

Note, that this will also work with string keys (which you mentioned in the comments) (note `:strs`):

```
    (reduce 
      (fn [m {:strs [key value]}] 
        (assoc m key value)) 
      {} 
      [{"key" "key_1" "value" "value_1"}, {"key" "key_2" "value" "value_2"}])
```

Another (point-free) version, when using keywords:

```
(partial (into {} (map (juxt :key :value))))
```

Since you mentioned in the comments, that you are using values from a DB, there might also be the chance, that you can switch to just return value tuples.  Then the whole operation is just:

```
(into {} [["key_1" "value_1"]["key_2" "value_2"]])
```

Also note, that the use of `vals` on a map and expecting "insertion order" is
dangerous.  Small maps are ordered only by accident:

```
user=> (take 3 (zipmap (range 3) (range 3)))
([0 0] [1 1] [2 2])
user=> (take 3 (zipmap (range 100) (range 100)))
([0 0] [65 65] [70 70])
```

Answer (score 1):

An other alternative to the nice answers is also:

```
(apply hash-map (mapcat vals [{:key "key_1" :value "value_1"}, {:key "key_2" :value "value_2"}]))
```

or:

```
((comp #(apply hash-map %) #(mapcat vals %)) [{:key "key_1" :value "value_1"}, {:key "key_2" :value "value_2"}])
```

which are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

As with clojure, so many ways to solve most problems.

```
(partial #(reduce (fn [r m] (assoc r (m :key) (m :value)))
                  {}
                  %)))
```

Not sure if the creation of anonymous functions violates your condition or not but this isn't adding functions to the namespace so I thought I'd throw it out there.  This also has the benefit of not requiring the keys in the input maps to be keywords as :key and :value can be replaced with values of any type since the map is in the function position.  For example:

```
(partial #(reduce (fn [r m] (assoc r (m "key") (m "value")))
                  {}
                  %)))
```